# Start job/event listener after commerce server start

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Does somebody know a possibility to start some code which runs directly after server start and just once? Of course, I could do some workaround like running a timed cron job that does nothing after the first time, but that is also actually ugly. I could also write my own spring bean and use the initialization phase, but then I cannot be sure that everything is up and running already.

Maybe there is an event or a spring bean I could refer to that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

This property will enable or disable all cronjobs starts after the server start.

```
cronjob.timertask.loadonstartup=false/true
```

But If you wanted a specific cronjob or some code run after the server start you can extend the ServletContextListner class to achieve your business case.

```
public class CronjobContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
@Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    //Code can be written to execute before server shuts down.  
  }
 
  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    // Write a code that needs to be executed just after the server starts
    
    }
    
    }
```

and register a new ContextListener in any of the web modules (web.xml).

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        <xyz>.CronjobContextListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
```